# Transform input back into a div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code

```
 $(document).on('click', '#editDetailBtn', function () {

    var input = $('<input id="#detailprimaryDescription" type="text" />');
    input.val($('#detailprimaryDescription').text());
    $('#detailprimaryDescription').replaceWith(input);


    $('#editDetailBtn').hide();
    $('#detailPrimaryCancel').show();
    $('#detailPrimarySave').show();

});


$(document).on('click', '#detailPrimaryCancel', function () {


    var input = $('<div id="#detailprimaryDescription" ></div>');
    //input.val($('#detailprimaryDescription').text());
    $('#detailprimaryDescription').replaceWith(input);


        $('#editDetailBtn').show();
        $('#detailPrimaryCancel').hide();
        $('#detailPrimarySave').hide();

});
```

what I am trying to achieve is to once cancel is clicked then it will turne the input field back into a div

http://jsfiddle.net/7XWAu/

Comment: Why are you writing `var input =` so many times?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're shooting for.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7XWAu/1/)

you don't need to place '#' at the beginning of an id in the dom, its only used to reference elements.

so basically, every where you had something like:

```
var input = $('<input id="#detailprimaryDescription_input" type="text" />');
```

you shouuld be doing something like:

```
var input = $('<input id="detailprimaryDescription_input" type="text" />');
```

once I cleaned that up it worked as it does in the fiddle.

I do want to say, that it would be a muchhhhhhh better practice to just show and hide a div containing all those inputs rather than manipulating the DOM to create / destroy them constantly.